# Why does a new entry in active admin on my category select box say 'cannot be empty' when I submit the form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin, categories

I am creating a profiles area in Active Admin. I created a scaffold called profile and with inherited resources its created the admin fields in the backend for me which is nice.

My only issue is when I add the details and select the category it says category cannot be left blank. This is baffling because its not at all blank.

Here is my setup:

app/admin/profile.rb

```
ActiveAdmin.register Profile do

    controller do
       def permitted_params
          params.permit profile: [:name, :profile_image, :content]
       end
    end
    controller do
        def find_resource
            scoped_collection.friendly.find(params[:id])
        end
    end

end
```

app/models/profile.rb

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_attached_file :profile_image, styles: {
        large: "600x450#",
        medium: "250x250#",
        small: "100x100#"
    }, :default_url => "/images/:style/filler.png"

    belongs_to :category
    validates :name, :profile_image, presence: true
    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

    attr_accessor :slug

end
```

The form is generated by Active Admin automatically for me.

The migration file looks like this:

```
class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :slug
      t.string :profile_image
      t.text :content


      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :profiles, :slug, unique: true
  end
end
```

Can anyone give any clues as to why this would be happening?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should check out this post in the ActiveAdmin documentation.

http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/2-resource-customization.html#belongs_to

Hope this helps!

Comment: hmmm no that seemed to throw more errors and my actual resource disappeared from the main top nav in active admin when I did that.

Comment: You should try changing the strong parameters set for the profile. Try appending params.permit profile: [:name, :profile_image, :content, categories[]] @Mdunbavan

Comment: How would I go about doing that for AA?

Comment: Try appending params.permit profile: [:name, :profile_image, :content, categories[]]